# unable to import breakpoint sass and compass

Tags: sass, breakpoints, compass-sass, compass

I have installed breakpoint gem 
[image]

But when i import it using @import "breakpoint" my gulp task fails and shows below error 
[image]

Gulp task i wrote.code is like below
[image]

But when i include breakpoint gem using absolute path then it works. Below is the screen shot [image]

What is the problem with statement @import "breakpoint". When gulp task fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to write the full path every time using breakpoint, add a path to your breakpoint.sass files at runtime in gulp:

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {
 gulp
 .src('./src/sass/*.scss')
 .pipe(sass({
   includePaths: ['./bower_components/breakpoint-sass/stylesheets']
 }))
 .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/css'))
});
```

credits: https://fedojo.com/breakpoint-sass-configuration-and-how-to-use-it-gulp-js-include-paths/